# check if variable is dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

when my function f is called with a variable I want to check if var is a pandas dataframe:

```
def f(var):
    if var == pd.DataFrame():
        print "do stuff"
```

I guess the solution might be quite simple but even with

```
def f(var):
    if var.values != None:
        print "do stuff"
```

I can't get it to work like expected.

Comment: Your code says "if `var` is equal to an empty dataframe". What you really want is "if the type of `var` is equal to the type `pd.DataFrame`". You can check that using `isinstance`

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance), nothing else:

```
if isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame):
    ... # do something
```

---

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says explicitly that `isinstance` is the preferred way to check types

```
No:  type(x) is pd.DataFrame
No:  type(x) == pd.DataFrame
Yes: isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame)
```

And don't even think about

```
if obj.__class__.__name__ = 'DataFrame':
    expect_problems_some_day()
```

`isinstance` handles inheritance (see [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python)). For example, it will tell you if a variable is a string (either `str` or `unicode`), because they derive from `basestring`)

```
if isinstance(obj, basestring):
    i_am_string(obj)
```

Specifically for `pandas` `DataFrame` objects:

```
import pandas as pd
isinstance(var, pd.DataFrame)
```

Answer (score 157):

Use the built-in `isinstance()` function.

```
import pandas as pd

def f(var):
    if isinstance(var, pd.DataFrame):
        print("do stuff")
```

Comment: How can you generalise this to the case in which a user may use the function you define, but didn't `import pandas as pd`, but instead just `import pandas`? Just perform an `or` on both possibilities, or is there something more sophisticated I don't know of?

Comment: A potential solution could be to put the import statement inside the function so there is no chance of a user importing pandas using some other method. To speed things up (to avoid importing the entire panda library for a simple check) you could just use something like `import pandas.DataFrame as panda_type` and then inside then check the array type using `isinstance(var, panda_type)`

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use the simplest solution: `type(x)`.

If it is Data Frame it will output `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.