# check if DataFrame column is boolean type

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame as below:

```py
>>> df
t                        v
2014-02-21 10:30:43  False
2014-02-21 10:31:34  False
2014-02-21 10:32:25  False

>>> df.dtypes
t   str
v   bool
```

I need to check if the `dtype` of this dataframe is `bool`. I tried with:

```py
>>> print('Type is Boolean = ', isinstance(df1, bool) )
Type is Boolean = False
```

How can I do this?

Source: [check if variable is dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808945/check-if-variable-is-dataframe)

Comment: Reference `dtype` directly.

Comment: How? Any sample code please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can print the `dtypes` of the columns:

```
In [2]:

import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[True,False,False]})
df
Out[2]:
       a
0   True
1  False
2  False

[3 rows x 1 columns]

In [3]:

df.dtypes

Out[3]:
a    bool
dtype: object
In [4]:

df.a.dtypes
Out[4]:
dtype('bool')
```

In your case, `df1.v.dtypes` should print the same output as above

The other thing to note that `isinstance(df, bool)` will not work as it is a pandas dataframe or more accurately:

```
In [7]:

type(df)
Out[7]:
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

The important thing to note is that `dtypes` is in fact a [`numpy.dtype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) you can do this to compare the name of the type with a string but I think `isinstance` is clearer and preferable in my opinion:

```
In [13]:

df.a.dtypes.name == 'bool'
Out[13]:
True
```

Comment: That's what I did. I need to check if `df.a.dtypes == bool`. How can I do this?

Comment: Okay. I had to do this: `if df1.v.dtype == 'bool':` to check if it is a boolean DataFrame. Thanks!

Comment: @curlyreggie `dytpes` is in fact a `numpy.dtype` see: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html, you could also do `df.a.dtypes.name == 'bool'` would yield `True`

Comment: Can we do something like `isinstance(df[col].dtype, bool)`?

Answer (score 1):

To get the dtype of a specific column, you have two ways:

1. Use `DataFrame.dtypes` which returns a Series whose index is the column header.

```py
$ df.dtypes.loc['v']

bool
```

2. Use [`Series.dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dtype.html) or [`Series.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dtypes.html) to get the dtype of a column. [Internally](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.3/pandas/core/series.py#L603-L609) `Series.dtypes` calls `Series.dtype` to get the result, so they are the same.

```
$ df['v'].dtype

bool

$ df['v'].dtypes

bool
```

All of the results return the same type

```py
$ type(df.dtypes.loc['v'])

<class 'numpy.dtype[bool_]'>

$ type(df['v'].dtype)

<class 'numpy.dtype[bool_]'>
```

To check if it is a bool type also has multiple ways

```
$ df['v'].dtype == 'bool'

True

$ np.issubdtype(df['v'].dtype, bool)

True

$ df['v'].dtype.type is np.bool_

True
```

---

You can also select the columns with specific types with [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

```py
$ df.select_dtypes('bool')

       v
0  False
1  False
2  False
```