# How to check if the model object is Xgboost or not in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to evaluate if the model object is xgboost or not, If it is not then raise an error

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

boston = load_boston()
X = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
y = pd.Series(boston.target)
regressor = xgb.XGBRegressor(
    n_estimators=100,
    reg_lambda=1,
    gamma=0,
    max_depth=3
)

regressor.fit(X, y)


type(regressor)
```

I tried using below two condition but getting failed
1st approach

```
if type(regressor) == 'xgboost.sklearn.XGBRegressor':
    print("Xgboost Model")
```

2nd approach

```
if not isinstance(regressor,XGBRegressor):
    raise TypeError("wrong input ")
```

**I need to evaluate model object for xgboost irrespective of whether it is classifier or regressor , it should check the condition for both**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider (preferred):

```
if isinstance(regressor, xgb.sklearn.XGBRegressor) or isinstance(regressor, xgb.sklearn.XGBClassifier):
    print("Xgboost Model")
else:
    raise TypeError("wrong input")
```

or, given your comment:

```
if regressor.__class__.__name__ in ['XGBRegressor', 'XGBClassifier']:
    print("Xgboost Model")
else:
    raise TypeError("wrong input")
```

Comment: is there any other way because xgb would depend on what others has used alias for importing , I need more of a general solution which could be used by everyone

Comment: Given your comments I would do the same `X.__class__.__name__ == 'DataFrame'`. But you may wish to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808945/check-if-variable-is-dataframe